# How to remove characters from the names of files in a folder?

Tags: linux, filenames, charset

I have a list files in a directory, but some of them has strange characters in the name. How can I rename only this files to delete this characters?

The computer OS is Red Hat, charset UTF-8.

[List of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2ABl.png)

Comment: Is it really a strange character or a question mark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try detox. From the manual page:

> **Name**
>
> **detox** - clean up filenames
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> detox [-hnLrv] [-s -sequence] [-f -configfile] [--dry-run] [--special]
>   file ...
>
> **Description**
>
> The detox utility renames files to make them easier to work with. It
>   removes spaces and other such annoyances. It'll also translate or
>   cleanup Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1) characters encoded in 8-bit ASCII,
>   Unicode characters encoded in UTF-8, and CGI escaped characters.
>
> **Sequences**
>
> detox is driven by a configurable series of filters, called a
>   sequence. Sequences are covered in more detail in detoxrc(5) and are
>   discoverable with the -L option. Some examples of default sequences
>   are iso8859_1 and utf_8.

It's available in RHEL 6 repositories, last time I checked. I'm not sure about RHEL 7. Before doing the actual cleanup, it's advisable to run `detox` with the `-n` (dry-run) switch. For example: `detox -rn /somedir`.

Comment: Not found in Centos 7 standard and epel repositories....Found in RHEL 6 .  also... in Fedora 23.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `detox`, or you want more control over the new file names, you can use standard tools.

`ls` with output to the terminal shows unprintable characters as `?`. If the displayed name (eg `ab?cd`) is unique (`ls ab?cd` shows a single file) you can simply use this mask in an `mv` command:

```
mv ab?cd ab_cd
```

`ls -b` shows unprintable characters as escape sequences (eg `ab\001cd`), though you can't use the displayed name in another command, but it does allow you to see all the affected files:

```
ls -b|grep '\\'     ; # includes names with embedded spaces
ls -b|grep '\\[^ ]' ; # excludes names with embedded spaces
```

`ls` with output to a file or pipe writes the literal file name: in this case you can get a list of file names with unprintables with:

```
ls|env LC_ALL=C grep '[^!-~]' ; # includes names with embedded spaces
ls|env LC_ALL=C grep '[^ -~]' ; # excludes names with embedded spaces
```

You can now pipe this output to a script to perform whatever renaming you require, as in:

```
ls|env LC_ALL=C grep '[^!-~]'|while l=`line`; do ... ; mv "$l" "$n" ; done
```

The omitted code is to formulate whatever new name `$n` you require. If you don't have `line`, you can use `while read l` instead, although this will not work properly with file names with leading or trailing spaces.